# sed character replacement in portion of a line

Tags: sed

New to sed and could use some help.
I would like to turn this "a/b/c  a/b/c" into this "a/b/c  a-b-c".
where a/b/c is any path.

thanks

Comment: You may confirm Dennis solution, which will donate him some points, and mark your problem as solved (instead of, or additional to your thanks in prosa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed 'h; s/ .*//; x; s/.* //; s:/:-:g; x; G; s/\n/ /'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use whitespace to delemit, I'd just use perl:

```
perl -ane '$F[1] =~ s/\//-/; print "@F\n"'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
after a space defines the second part of the line
I tried your first suggestion, but it did not work for me
echo "a/b/c a/b/c"|sed 's@\( .*\)-@\1/@g'
a/b/c a/b/c

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened when I pasted in the first pattern; it's obviously completely wrong. But the perl one's way more robust if you want to use whitespace to delimit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk,

```
$ echo "a/b/c a/b/c" | awk '{gsub("/","-",$NF)}1'
a/b/c a-b-c
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
echo "a/b/c a/b/c" | sed ':a;s|\(.* [^/]*\)/|\1-|;ta'
a/b/c a-b-c
```

Or this:

```
echo "a/b/c a/b/c" | sed 's/.* //;h;y/\//-/;x;G;y/\n/ /'
a/b/c a-b-c
```